# make4ht complains about "module 'luaxml-domobject' not found"

Tags: html, make4ht

I have installed `make4ht` using the command `tlmgr install make4ht`.

Now when I enter the command `make4ht foo.tex`, I get this error:

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo.tex
...texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/filters/make4ht-domfilter.lua:2: module 'luaxml-domobject' not found:
        no field package.preload['luaxml-domobject']
        [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'
        [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'
```

What else do I need to install before I can use `make4ht` successfully?

Comment: You will need also `luaxml` and `tex4ht`.

Comment: @michal.h21 Since I was using the command `make4ht foo.tex mathjax`, I had to install some additional packages too with `sudo tlmgr install make4ht tex4ht luaxml environ trimspaces`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me answer how I resolved this issue. The comment by @michal.h21 helped.

Note that points 2 to 6 show false starts or attempts that did not lead to good looking results. Only the last point i.e. point 7 led to nice results.

1. Create a file `foo.tex` which I will use to test that `make4ht` works successfully:

   ```tex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \title{Demo}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{align}
   1 + 0 & = 1, \label{eq1} \\
   1 + 1 & = 2, \label{eq2} \\
   e^{i \pi} = -1. \label{eq3}
   \end{align}

   Equation \( \eqref{eq1} \), \( \eqref{eq2} \) and \( \eqref{eq3} \)
   describe eternal truths.

   The equation \( e^{i \pi} = -1 \) can also be rewritten as \( e^{i \pi}
   + 1 = 0 \) which is known as Euler's identity.
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Install `make4ht` and compile `foo.tex` to `foo.html` as follows:

   ```sh
   sudo tlmgr install make4ht
   make4ht foo
   ```

   This led to the following error:

   ```
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo
   ...texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/filters/make4ht-domfilter.lua:2: module 'luaxml-domobject' not found:
           no field package.preload['luaxml-domobject']
           [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'
           [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'
   ```
3. Install `make4ht` and `luaxml` and try again:

   ```sh
   sudo tlmgr install make4ht luaxml
   make4ht foo
   ```

   This led to the following error:

   ```
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo
   [ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
   [ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
   [ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?        LaTeX Error: File `tex4ht.sty' not found.
   [ERROR]   htlatex: ?    2        Emergency stop.
   [FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
   ```
4. Install `make4ht`, `luaxml`, and `tex4ht`, and try again:

   ```sh
   sudo tlmgr install make4ht luaxml tex4ht
   make4ht foo
   ```

   The conversion succeeded this time:

   ```
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo
   sh: dvipng: command not found
   sh: dvipng: command not found
   sh: dvipng: command not found
   sh: dvipng: command not found
   sh: dvipng: command not found
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
   ```

   Here is how the output `foo.html` looked:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
   <head><title></title> 
   <meta charset='utf-8' /> 
   <meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
   <meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
   <link href='foo.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /> 
   <meta content='foo.tex' name='src' /> 
   </head><body>
   <!-- l. 6 --><p class='noindent'>
   </p><table class='align'>
                              <tr><td class='align-odd'>1 + 0</td>                               <td class='align-even'> = 1<span class='cmmi-10'>,</span></td>                                                      <td class='align-label'><a id='x1-2r1'></a>(1)
                              </td></tr><tr><td class='align-odd'>1 + 1</td>                               <td class='align-even'> = 2<span class='cmmi-10'>,</span></td>                                                      <td class='align-label'><a id='x1-3r2'></a>(2)
                              </td></tr><tr><td class='align-odd'><span class='cmmi-10'>e</span><sup><span class='cmmi-7'>iπ</span></sup> = <span class='cmsy-10'>−</span>1<span class='cmmi-10'>.</span></td>                           <td class='align-even'></td>                               <td class='align-label'><a id='x1-4r3'></a>(3)                                                      </td></tr></table>
   <!-- l. 12 --><p class='noindent'>Equation <img alt='(1)  ' src='foo0x.png' class='math' />, <img alt='(2)  ' src='foo1x.png' class='math' /> and <img alt='(3)  ' src='foo2x.png' class='math' /> describe eternal truths.
   </p><!-- l. 15 --><p class='indent'>   The equation <img alt='eiπ = − 1  ' src='foo3x.png' class='math' /> can also be rewritten as <img alt='eiπ + 1 = 0  ' src='foo4x.png' class='math' /> which is known
   as Euler’s identity. </p> 
   </body> 
   </html>
   ```

   The math rendered using HTML and images does not look great.
5. Render math using MathJax:

   ```sh
   make4ht foo mathjax
   ```

   The conversion fails:

   ```
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo
   [ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
   [ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
   [ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?        LaTeX Error: File `environ.sty' not found.
   [ERROR]   htlatex: ?    22       Emergency stop.
   [FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
   ```
6. Install `make4ht`, `luaxml`, `tex4ht`, and `environ` and try again:

   ```sh
   sudo tlmgr install make4ht luaxml tex4ht environ
   make4ht foo mathjax
   ```

   It fails again:

   ```
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo
   [ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
   [ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
   [ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?        LaTeX Error: File `trimspaces.sty' not found.
   [ERROR]   htlatex: ?    17       Emergency stop.
   [FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
   ```
7. Install `make4ht`, `luaxml`, `tex4ht`, `environ`, and `trimspaces` and try again:

   ```sh
   sudo tlmgr install make4ht luaxml tex4ht environ trimspaces
   make4ht foo mathjax
   ```

   The conversion is successful:

   ```
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo
   [STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
   ```

   Here is the output `foo.html`:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html xml:lang='en-US' lang='en-US'> 
   <head><title></title> 
   <meta charset='utf-8' /> 
   <meta name='generator' content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' /> 
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' /> 
   <link href='foo.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /> 
   <meta name='src' content='foo.tex' /> 
   <script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", inlineMath: [ ["\\\(","\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, processEnvironments: true, packages: ['base', 'color', 'ams'] }, loader: { load: ['[tex]/color', '[tex]/ams'] } }; </script> 
    <script id='MathJax-script' type='text/javascript' async='async' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js'></script>  
   </head><body>
   <!-- l. 10 --><p class='noindent'>\begin{align} 1 + 0 &amp; = 1, \label{eq1} \\ 1 + 1 &amp; = 2, \label{eq2} \\ e^{i \pi } = -1. \label{eq3} \end{align}
   </p><!-- l. 12 --><p class='noindent'>Equation \( \eqref{eq1} \), \( \eqref{eq2} \) and \( \eqref{eq3} \) describe eternal truths.
   </p><!-- l. 15 --><p class='indent'>   The equation \( e^{i \pi } = -1 \) can also be rewritten as \( e^{i \pi } + 1 = 0 \) which is known as Euler’s identity.
   </p> 
   </body> 
   </html>
   ```

   Here is an example JSFiddle that shows the output: https://jsfiddle.net/9xubrm47/.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu (20.04), I had `make4ht` installed through the `apt` standard package `texlive-extra-utils`.

And I have a similar error :

```bash
...texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/filters/make4ht-domfilter.lua:2: module 'luaxml-domobject' not found:
        no field package.preload['luaxml-domobject']
        [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'
        [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luaxml-domobject'
```

**To solve the error, I just installed the package** `texlive-luatex` :

```bash
sudo apt install texlive-luatex
```

(It seems that there is a missing dependency for the package `texlive-extra-utils`)